# Rails, is it possible to include the string length in a validation message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the next model with validation rules:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { 
    minimum: 15,
    too_short: "is too short, yours have '?', it must be of 15 characters minimum" }
  validates :text, presence: true, length: { 
    minimum: 30, 
    too_short: "is too short, yours have  '?', it must be of 30 characters minimum" }
end
```

In the message, I want to include the length of the current value (for the title and the text), is that possible? Or there is another approach?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about internationalization, you can create a custom validates method for adding unique error messages:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title_minimum_length

  private

  def title_minimum_length
    error.add("Title is too short: #{title.length} given but needs at least 15") if title.length <= 15
  end
end
```

[Internationalization reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes)

Comment: You can still use `I18n` by just defining your own key, `errors.add(I18n.l('somekey'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can add property value in the message with lamda:

`validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 30, too_short: ->(object, data){"is too short, yours have #{data[:value].length} characters, it must be of 30 characters minimum"}}`